# setting location.href does not work from a <a> click

Tags: javascript

This is code I took over from a colleague who left:

```
<input type="text" class="value" placeholder="0"></span><br>
<a href="/model/act/id/'.$model->id.'" class="act act-a" url="/model/act/id/'.$model->id.'">Act Now</a>

<script>
    $('.act-a').click(function(){
        if(parseInt($('.value').val())>0){
            //window.location.href = window.location.origin + $(this).attr('url') + '?r=' + parseInt($('.value').val());
            window.location.replace("www.google.com");
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

When I click on the link, I never get redirected to www.google.com. Originally what I want is to execute the commented code, but setting www.google.com to debug, I think to realize that my redirection is being ignored, and instead the original href from the  is used!

How can I set window.location.href when a link has been clicked, adding a GET parameter?

Comment: `return true;` tells the browser to do the link's default action.  Remove both the return statements, and instead add `e.preventDefault();` (make sure to change the `.click` to `$('.act-a').click(function(e){`).

Comment: @Rocket What is the reson to use e.preventDefault() instead of return false?

Comment: @FAngel: I just persoanlly prefer to use `preventDefault`

Comment: @Rocket me too) It was just interesting - maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: FYI: `preventDefault` just stops the default event action from happening, while `return false` also stops bubbling (does both `preventDefault` and `stopPropagation`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`return true;` tells the browser to do the link's default action.  So, the browser is following the link instead of running `window.location`.

Remove both the return statements, and instead add `e.preventDefault();`

```
$('.act-a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if(parseInt($('.value').val(), 10) > 0){
        window.location.href = window.location.origin + $(this).attr('url') + '?r=' + parseInt($('.value').val(), 10);
    }
});
```

P.S. You should add `,10` to `parseInt` to make sure the number is parsed as base 10.

Comment: That works marvelously, thanks! I am using preventDefault because in both cases I override the link: if the value is not set, it's supposed to do nothing; if the value is set, I need to pass it as a GET param. If I understand correctly, this means that if some other handler down the road is hooked to the event, it would continue executing if I don't use 'return'; as I know there's no other handler I like the preventDefault (thanks gonchuki and +1 for explanation)

Comment: @fablife: I'm pretty sure `return false` would stop all other handlers, whereas `preventDefault` just stops the default action.

Answer (score 2):

Change reutrn true after window.location to return false;

```
$('.act-a').click(function(){
    if(parseInt($('.value').val())>0){
        //window.location.href = window.location.origin + $(this).attr('url') + '?r=' + parseInt($('.value').val());
        window.location.replace("www.google.com");
        return false;
    }
    return false;
});
```

Returning false on events such as click, submit and others prevent the default behavior of such event. Use return true only if you want to run a function and then let the event propagate to the other regular listeners such as following a link's href, continue normal form submission etc... This article is helpful for event bubbling basics: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html